# Uglify RequireJS modules without concatenating them

Tags: optimization, requirejs, uglifyjs, r.js

Is it possible to uglify all the RequireJS modules without concatenating them into a single file? (I know the other way round is possible with `optimize: "none"`).

Comment: Since this would effectively bypass r.js and only use UglifyJS, why not just invoke UglifyJS directly from your build tool?

Comment: Yes, @kryger is right. It's an all-or-nothing build process, so optimization includes minification and concatenation.

Comment: There's no need to put "RequireJS" in the question title or in the question's prose description. Given that you tagged your question with [tag:requirejs], then *obviously* we're talking about modules that RequireJS can load, and not modules in SystemJS' native format, for instance, that RequireJS cannot load.

Comment: I believe it is required because more chances of getting to this page for those who google or use stack-overflow search for similar issues. Also without `RequireJS` the subject line itself will be meaningless and cannot expect everybody would notice the tag. Anyways thanks for the edit and answer!.

Answer (score 0):

I know [uglifyjs-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-folder) have this option, with parameters `-e` and `-o` referencing a folder (not a file).

ex:

`uglifyjs-folder "%CD%" -e -o "%CD%\subfolder"`

(obs: `%CD%` in Windows gets the current folder)

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* use `r.js` to uglify the files without concatenating them. If you do not provide any module name in the configuration options (i.e. you don't use `modules` nor specify `name`), then `r.js` will process each file from `baseUrl` individually, and thus will uglify each file without concatenation. For instance, this trivial build configuration:

```
{
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "build",
}
```

causes `r.js` to process each file from `js` individually and copy it into `build` after uglifying the file. No concatenation happens no matter how many files you have in `js`. With the configuration above, `r.js` will not trace any dependencies between modules because it does not need to trace dependencies to do its work.

This being said, I would not use `r.js` for the purpose of uglifying the files individually *unless* there was some *additional* feature of `r.js` I'd need to use. For instance, it may be expedient to use `cjsTranslate: true` to have `r.js` convert CommonJS modules to AMD, and perform the uglification at the same time.